# git-tf configure problems with space (%20)

Tags: git, tfs, git-tf, tfs-2013

Currently trying to copy a local git repository to my 2013 TFS server.

When I try to use this command:
`git tf configure http://ip:8080/tfs/collection%20name/ $/project`

I get the error:
`git-tf: 'http://ip:8080/tfs/collection%20name/' is not a valid URL`

The TFS collection name contains a space but as far as I know you can replace it with %20 and it should work.

Comment: Don't use Git TF; it is deprecated and inferior to Git TFS.

Answer (score 0):

`TFS2013` and `git-tf` are old, so I can't get similar environment like yours.

I assume you need to check if you're using correct url, open TFS web portal and you'll see the correct url:

[image]

If the issue persists though you're using correct url with git-tf 2.0.3 release, there might be an issue with git-tf tool. I think you can try [Git Tfs tool](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) like **Daniel** suggested above since the `Git-TF` had reached its end-of-life after 2013.

(Ps: In my test, Git TFS can recognize the collection name which contains space(`%20`) well.)